# Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView

Tags: android, android-layout, ads, android-inflate

I tried to add ads to my app. But it reports the error:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML
>   file line #9: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView

Here is my `build.gradle` (module: app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.firebasedemoapp"
    minSdkVersion 23
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
            optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.6.0'
}
```

Here is my `build.gradle` (project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here is my MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MobileAds.initialize( this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
        AdView mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

}
```

I expect the ads to add to my app, but it reports the error inflating.

Edit:
Add my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

stack trace:

```
2019-04-23 11:20:19.790 23516-23516/com.example.firebasedemoapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.firebasedemoapp, PID: 23516
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.firebasedemoapp/com.example.firebasedemoapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at com.example.firebasedemoapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/R$styleable;
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzk.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzae.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzae.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzae.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.BaseAdView.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
    at com.example.firebasedemoapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
2019-04-23 11:20:19.790 23516-23516/com.example.firebasedemoapp E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.R$styleable" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.firebasedemoapp-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.firebasedemoapp-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.firebasedemoapp-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.firebasedemoapp-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.firebasedemoapp-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.firebasedemoapp-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.firebasedemoapp-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.firebasedemoapp-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.firebasedemoapp-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.firebasedemoapp-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.firebasedemoapp-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.firebasedemoapp-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.firebasedemoapp-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
```

Comment: The error is from the XML, yet you haven't posted that

Comment: Please also provide the complete [stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23353174).

Comment: I just added. Could you please help me to fix it?

Comment: @yxy Please add complete stack trace. I mean logs around `android.view.InflateException`.

Comment: @StanleyKou Just added.

Comment: It seems that everything is ok... Will you try "File - Invalidate Cache / Restart"?

Answer (score 1):

Remove **xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"** from **com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView**. You already add it to **android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout**. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Use **implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'** rather than **implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.6.0'**. You are using a super old version of firebase ads. Current version is **implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.2.0'**.

If you want to implement firebase ads follow this documention
https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start